# Escaping a pipe in a vue-i18n translation

Tags: vue.js, escaping, vue-i18n

We need to have a translation in vue-i18n where the translated string have to contain a pipe character ( | ).

But in vue-i18n translation files, the pipe is used as delimiter for pluralization. We tried several ways to escape it (single or double backslash, etc.) but nothing worked…

I couldn’t find anything talking about that in vue-18n documentation.

I didn’t found issues talking about that in the vue-i18n github repository.

Has anybody already faced it and found a workaround?

Comment: We'll try the escaped character.
But we've always used $t, and never $tc, and in our webapp, $t does pluralization. Are we on an very aged version ? We are in 8.10.0

Comment: Everything should work on version 8.10.0. What do you mean when you say: "In our webapp $t does pluralization."? If you have some custom method which then calls $t or $tc, maybe that is not the best approach, and the problem lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the problematic.
You can solve your problem either by using `$t` instead of `$tc`, since `$t` method will not do a pluralization, or by putting pipe unicode: `\u007C` instead of `|` in your localization string.
Hope that any of these solutions will work for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Correct way to escape pipe & other special characters would be to use literal interpolation syntax.

```
"User profile {'|'} AppName"
```

https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#literal-interpolation